# Monitor user to query processlist

Tags: mysql, permissions, process

We have a corporate monitoring system based in Zabbix. Its MySQL monitoring is quite basic, so I want to add more info. To do so, I've done a script that retrieves this info from MySQL and sends it to Zabbix.

Among the retrieved info, I want to get current connections, but I've only managed to do so with the root user. I've created a zabbix user with SELECT and PROCESS permissions* and tried `mysqladmin -u zabbix processlist`, but I get `Access denied; you need the PROCESS privilege for this operation`.

```
show grants for 'zabbix'@'%';
+----------------------------------------------+
| Grants for zabbix@%                          |
+----------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'zabbix'@'%' |
+----------------------------------------------+
SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

How can I get zabbix user to retrieve processlist?

* Yes, I've flushed permissions

Comment: Would you please edit and add: the particular query you're trying to run; also, the output of `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can create a DB user whose sole purpose in life is to collect the processlist.

Your error message indicates that zabbix does not have the [**PROCESS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege.

Without the [**PROCESS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege, zabbix can only view the processlist of zabbix users. Not much fun, eh?

But **WAIT**, you said

```
mysqladmin -u zabbix processlist
```

That will attempt to connect as `zabbix@localhost` which you did not define. Please note:

- `zabbix@localhost` will authenticate via the socket file
- `zabbix@'%'` will authenticate via TCP/IP

Simply run

```
GRANT SELECT, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost';
```

and your troubles should be over.

Without adding another MySQL user, just specify the TCP/IP protocol

```
mysqladmin -u zabbix --protocol=tcp processlist
```

Comment: so, maybe this is a stupid question but... doesn't 'zabbix'@'%'  include 'zabbix'@'localhost'?

Comment: They are not the same. Using `localhost` will authenticate a DB Connection via socket file. Using `%` implies that TCP/IP must be used. See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17110/877 for a detailed explanation on user authentication. I also updated my answer to address authenticating with TCP/IP.

Comment: Saying `GRANT SELECT, PROCESS ON *.*` you give zabbix permission to read from any database and table (`*.*`), don't you?